# Can I run a 32bit version of Windows XP in a Virtual Machine, on a 64bit machine running Ubuntu (64bit)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, 64-bit, virtual-machine, 32-bit

I believe my title is enough..
I have a 64bit Computer running Ubuntu (64bit). Can I run a 32bit version of Windows XP in a Virtual Machine (VirtualBox)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

The guest and host machines don't need to use the same number of bits in instructions/memory addressing.

That said, it's certainly *possible* that a specific Virtual Machine application will not support this or will have bugs that cause problems when you set it up that way (but you've not mentioned any specific VM software?)

Comment: Thanks, any comments on virtual box?

Comment: I've not used it myself, but from all accounts it sounds pretty mature/stable (though not at the same level as VMWare; if you're using it for a commercial application I'd go with VMware/Parallels). Performance will of course depend on what you want to do... You'll want to have a read of the (very thorough) user manual for linux installation (e.g. it has a kernel module pre-requisite). Windows is very well supported, so you shouldn't have any issues with the guest OS.

Answer (score 2):

I run a 32 bit os (Windows 2000) in a VM with VirtualBox on a 64 bit Ubuntu 10.4 LTS.  So the answer to your question is YES.